# Minimizing Realm File Size: Practical approach

Tags: swift, realm

I have a Realm db which is written to asynchronously, and the file size seems to grow exponentially during an initial load from a Rest API. It continues to grow after I have finished writing to it, topping out at 1.5GB.

Using a `writeCopyToPath`, the underlying data is 1.5 Mb.

Below is my insert command:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("background", nil)) {
let realm = try! Realm()
let this_activity = DataManager().getExerciseById(activity_id)
if this_activity != nil {
for (_, subJson) in data_ball["mapPoints"] {
    let  map_point = MapPoint(this_activity:this_activity!, json: subJson)
    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(map_point)
    }
 }   
}
```

To query I have a data manager which is instantiated by each ViewController (but not held on to after it returns with data).  The Data Manager has query methods like this:

```
func getSegments(activity_id:String) -> [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]{
    var intervals:[Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] = []
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", activity_id)
    let intervals = realm.objects(Segment).filter(predicate).sorted("startTime", ascending: true)
    for interval in intervals {
        intervals.append(interval.toDictionary())
    }
    return intervals
}
```

These queries and insert operations can happen during the same time period. What strategies should I use to stop it from growing like this?

Comment: Which threads are your inserts performed on?

Comment: I start a new thread using `        dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("background", nil)) {` should i just remove this?

Comment: Can you try adding an autorelease pool around the entirety of the code in the block you pass to `dispatch_async`?

Comment: Will do! thanks for your help- Realm support is awesome! (and your db is pretty good too!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely you're holding a reference to an older version of the data, preventing it from being reclaimed. Take a look at the [File size & tracking of intermediate versions](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#file-size--tracking-of-intermediate-versions) section of Realm's documentation for more information.

Comment: Are you referring to an instance of the db e.g.. `let realm = try! Realm()` or the Realm objects themselves?  I want to hold on to the objects, but i don't plan on writing to them- how could I proceed?

Comment: Both. If you can share a little more information about how your code is structured that writes to the database I can expand my answer to cover the issues that are likely to address you. My suspicion is that since you're doing this as a result of networking, that you're doing writes on blocks executed on dispatch queues. If that's the case then the solution is likely to be to wrap your use of Realm in autorelease pools.